# Returning db connection to HikariCP pool with Slick 3.1.x

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, hikaricp

I'm setting up a slick Database object from typesafe config like so:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config

class DatabaseService(configKey: String, config: Config) {
  val driver = slick.driver.MySQLDriver
  import driver.api._
  val db = Database.forConfig(configKey, config)
}
```

The config object tells Slick to use HikariCP, like so:

```
db {
  numThreads = 5
  connectionTimeout = 30000
  maximumPoolSize = 26
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false"
  user = "root"
  password = "root"
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
}
```

After instantiating the DatabaseService I can then run queries by running `dbService.db.run(someQuery)`.

The first question is do I need to do something to get a connection from the pool or does that happen behind the scenes when I invoke `db.run()`?

Secondly, once that query or queries execute how do I return the current database connection to the connection pool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The first question is do I need to do something to get a connection from the pool or does that happen behind the scenes when I invoke db.run()?

That happens behind the scenes.

> Secondly, once that query or queries execute how do I return the current database connection to the connection pool?

Thats also happens behind the scenes.

Here is the [relevant code for both questions](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/backend/DatabaseComponent.scala#L235-L241). Basically, is acquires a session, executes the given action (in your case, `someQuery`) and then release the session (closes it). Digging a little more at the code, you can see that the JDBC implementation creates a [`BaseSession`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L38-L47) which [holds a connection](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L414-L418) and also [closes it when the close method is invoked](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.1.1/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L432-L434).

Also, from [the docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html#populating-the-database):

> Database connections and transactions are managed automatically by Slick. By default connections are acquired and released on demand and used in auto-commit mode.

Comment: Awesome thanks for linking the code in your answer! Do you happen to know where I can find a list of complete config options for the Database class? Doesn't seem to be one in the docs.

Comment: At [the scaladocs, `forConfig` method](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef@forConfig(path:String,config:com.typesafe.config.Config,driver:java.sql.Driver,classLoader:ClassLoader):JdbcBackend.this.Database) (you need to expand the method documentation). It was linked [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html).

Comment: Ah I totally missed that expand icon. Thanks again!